# Does boost::compute support const modifiers?

Tags: c++, boost, opencl, gpu, boost-compute

Is it possible to set which function arguments have 'global' or 'const' modifiers? Or how at least to inspect the code of generated function on a per function basis (to insert it manually)?

Closest thing I saw was [`BOOST_COMPUTE_STRINGIZE_SOURCE`](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/example/opencv_histogram.cpp#L40) where you write all kernel code by hand, save it into string, compile manually, call using `set_arg(argId, wrapedItems)` and `queue.enqueue_nd_range_kernel` that looks so much more complicated than:

```
    BOOST_COMPUTE_CLOSURE(ftype, kick, (ftype beam), (__const voltage), {
        return beam * sin(beam + voltage);
    });
```

one would hope for.

Comment: Did you mean "Is it possible to se*e*"? Did you mean "which *method* has a const modifier'? What do you mean by 'global modifier', maybe `static`?

Comment: I think he meant https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/global.html

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal Ah, thanks. If so, they aren't standard C or C++, they are specific extensions to deal with GPU stuff, right?

Comment: Yes, I think the original question is confusing. boost::compute wraps around `__global` and `__constant` extensions from OpenCL in a better C++ api, I'm not sure it makes sense to mix them.

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal: my problem is that when I define `BOOST_COMPUTE_CLOSURE` and pass arguments I can not set `__const` or `__local` for CLOSURE variables and it is not clear with which argument is passed fo the function.

Answer (score 1):

[`BOOST_COMPUTE_CLOSURE()`](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/BOOST_COMPUTE_CLOSURE.html) constructs a function that can be passed to Boost.Compute functions like `transform()` or `sort()`. Compared to the [`BOOST_COMPUTE_FUNCTION()`](http://boostorg.github.io/compute/BOOST_COMPUTE_FUNCTION.html), it allows capturing of in-scope C++ variables. It does not construct a OpenCL kernel object, so there is not really a need to specify an address space qualifier because it never operates on pointers, only on values.

However, if have your own kernel and want to pass a `__constant` buffer as an argument to it, then use a `constant_buffer_iterator`.